# Page shifts slightly when Bootstrap modal rendered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've narrowed this down as much as possible in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3re6onp/1/).  When you expand the right side as much as possible (to make Result area wide) and click on the Sign Up button, you will notice the page under the modal shifts slightly to the left.  I've seen elsewhere on SO that this is sometimes due to using `class row` without grid elements, but I have grid elements in my `row`.

Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: its a default modal behavior , nothing can be done about it ! . thats how bootstrap comes packaged , unless u decide to dig into the modal code urself and change a few things ! :)

Comment: thanks for the response Alex.  I guess I need to live with it although I don't think it looks that nice.

Comment: i would say "probably yes" , you will have to live with it . if u see in the developer tools "DOM and style inspector" , u'll notice a new element being added , I.E. "a modal backdrop" , a new new div , which is generated on the fly and added to the HTML , if i am not wrong , thats whts causing the problem !